# post data from database through link

Tags: php, mysql

```
<a href="<?php echo $row['plant_name'];?>"><?php echo $row['plant_name'];?></a>
```

it echo the desired ['plant_name'] which  appear on the link. how can i post the other information of the plant when the link is clicked. thanks

Answer (score 0):

This question begs for many more details, but let's pretend we know what you're asking here...

I think you want to know how to get specific information based on a $_GET variable, right?

SO your link would be better suited to operate off a slug or an id instead of a name...

```
<a href="/plants.php?id=<?php echo $row['plant_id'];?>"><?php echo $row['plant_name'];?></a>
```

Assuming you have a file called plants.php and you have a database column called plant_id...

Then in your plants.php file you would call the database and select on the $_GET id...

```
<?php

// basic database connection info here

$sql = "SELECT * FROM `plants` WHERE `plant_id` = '".mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['id'])."'";
$res = mysql_query($sql);
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res))
{
    echo $row['plant_name'];
}
?>
```

Assuming you have a plants table as well.

This is a VERY crude example on using $_GET vars to pull product info. It will help getting you started if this is what you needed, but there is definitely a lot more to learn - specifically about security holes in $_GET dependency when not understood properly - that you should read up on.

Answer (score 0):

simple and easy way is j query 
if you want to submit post data have to use form element

try like this

For example, consider the HTML:

```
<form id="target" action="destination.html">
  <input type="text" value="Hello there" />
  <input type="submit" value="Go" />
</form>
<div id="other">
  Trigger the handler
</div>
```

JS code

```
 $('#other').click(function() {
 $('#target').submit();
 });
```